# how connect excel 2007 for delphi7

Tags: delphi, excel-2007, delphi-2007

I can connect with paradox base, oracle etc.
Now I want to work with excel 
how can I do it ?

Comment: Too general. Voting to close.

Comment: Tried OleDB with ADO and failed? Use the ACE engine instead of the JET engine..

Comment: Do you mean use an Excel sheet as a database or let the user edit an Excel sheet in you application?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ADO, you can set the connectionstring like this:

ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyWorkBooks\myDataBook.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;';

http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa090903a.htm

Comment: That's not gonna work for workbooks that are not compatible with earlier versions (xlsx).

Comment: When you change OLEDB.4.0 to OLEDB.12.0 you can open xlsx.